# Why isn't this code working when i try to use IFFE

Tags: javascript, function, iife

I tried to run this code.

```
var temp = (function () {
var a =10;
return {
    function (a) {
        console.log('Value of a is ' + a);
    }
 }
})();
temp();
```

I expect IIFE to return the function and assign it to the temp variable, but 
instead, I get the error below.

```
Uncaught TypeError: temp is not a function
```

Whats wrong with that?

Comment: You are returning an object literal with a property called "function", which contains your function. You should return the function itself.

Comment: + that `a` in the returned function is not what you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a block inside which a function is defined. Instead return the function directly. Please find the below code for reference.

```
   var temp = (function () {
   var a =10;
   return function (a) {
      console.log('Value of a is ' + a);
      }
   })();
   temp();
```

And if you want to access the value of 'a' from the outer scope then use a different name for the parameter in the inner function.

```
   var temp = (function () {
   var a =10;
   return function (b) {
      a = b || a;
      console.log('Value of a is ' + a);
      }
   })();
   temp();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the object literals from the return & return a named function

```js
var temp = (function() {
  var a = 10;
  return function test(a) {
    console.log('Value of a is ' + a);
  }
})();
temp();
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you got confused with '{}' instead of '()'.

```
var temp = (function () {
var a =10;
return (
    function (a) {
        console.log('Value of a is ' + a);
    }
 )
})();
temp(<pass 'a' here>);
```

Further you are returning a function definition, which is not bound to 'a'. Try calling 'temp' with an argument.